How to take a sum of multiplied values spanning multiple tables
Below is a pseudo SQL query that helps represent the logic I'm trying to achieve with the structure I am working with:
SELECT 
    t3.ColA, t3.ColB 
FROM 
    t3 
WHERE 
    t3.ColA IN (SELECT t2.ColA, t2.ColC 
                FROM t2 
                WHERE t2.ColD IN (SELECT DISTINCT t1.ColD 
                                  FROM t1 
                                  WHERE t1.ColE = '1234'));

I would like to retrieve a SUM(ColB * ColC) where the multiplication only occurs on WHERE t2.ColA = t3.ColA pairings
Any advice on how I should best go about this?
EDIT: I do understand the above query would likely be better written as a JOIN, I'm fairly new to SQL so JOINs are not my strong suite, if someone could assist with this as well, I would greatly greatly appreciate.
Provided here are sample tables with data to show structure / example. I apologize, I'm also fairly new to StackOverflow.
t1 table:



ColD
ColE




27
1234


32
5678


46
9624



t2 table:



ColA
ColC
ColD




12345
1
27


26743
2
27


43621
3
27


12345
2
46


26743
5
52



t3 table:



ColA
ColB




12345
5


26743
10


43621
3



My expected output if conducting this query for ColE='1234' would be:
ColD selection would be '27' from t1
So the first 3 rows from t2 would be selected along with the top 3 rows in t3.
sum(5 * 1, 10 * 2, 3 * 3) = 34


I suppose it's better to use JOIN and GROUP BY than nested subqueries.

Please update your question with sample data for the tables and the result you want to achieve - all as editable text, formatted as tables

Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

I.e. provide a complete [mcve]. And add tag for the dbms used - different solutions can be possible.

Use joins:
select sum(colB * colC)
from t1
join t2 on t2.colD = t1.colD
join t3 on t3.colA = t2.colA
where t1.colE = '1234'

